# Event fault in Firefox

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a problem accessing the 'event' in Firefox. The following code works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox I get a "event is not defined" error.

```
<tr onclick="rowSelected('thisRowType')">
  ... row content ...
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function rowSelected(type) {
        var eventRow = event.currentTarget; // here I get the error
    }
</script>
```

I understand that Firefox does not find any variable called event, but I have not been able to find anything other than 'event' should also be defined in Firefox.

So how could I access the current event in Firefox, or how should a redesign look like?
Please note that I have different rows supplying different values for 'type'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
function rowSelected(event, type) {
    var eventRow = event.currentTarget; // here I get the error
}
```

You where not allowing the event argument to be passed. Well, you were but it was being passed into the type variable. Now `event` will contain the `currentTarget` value.

**EDIT**

Oh wait! You wish to pass the row type too.

This should do it!

```
<tr onclick="rowSelected(event, 'thisRowType')">
  ... row content ...
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function rowSelected(event, type) {
        var eventRow = event.currentTarget; // here I get the error
        alert(type);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I worked :-) I was not aware that event is send automatic as parameter and thus highjacking the 'type' param. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yep, it's quite hidden, usually if you don't wish to pass any other parameters other than the event parameter you can just use the onclick value like this `onclick="rowSelected"` and it will automatically pass the event parameter.